# How to correctly pass files in AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm passing information in AJAX to `"my.php"` like this

HTML

```
<textarea name="Comment"></textarea> 
<input id="images" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" multiple="multiple"  /> 
<input id="new_review" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

JS

```
jQuery('input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://site/my.php',
            data: {
                post_id: 15 ,
                text: jQuery("textarea[name=Comment]").val(),
                images: jQuery("#images").val(),
            },
            success:function(data){
                window.location='https://site/my.url'
            }
        });
    });
```

The textarea passes well but my file input only passes a fakepath and the name of the file. How to correctly pass the file to `"my.php"` in a clean and simple way ?

Comment: use FormData please

Comment: Or there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload, or about 20 others. Have you done any research?

Comment: @KenLee Thanks for the lead =) I appreciate

Comment: No problem. In future please do a bit more basic research then you don't waste your effort creating a question which is a duplicate of an easily-google-able one :-)

Comment: @ADyson That's true, I spent time but I'm not familiar with all the possibilities and some of them look very complicated. Not the one you redirect to. Thanks again !

Comment: Sure, but if you google the exact title of your question then the links I provided are the first results on the page...

Comment: @ADyson true. do ! =)